# Android Studio Run: install comes to no result

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know where this has suddenly come from, because I have done never special with the IDE. If I press the Run-button in Android Studio, then the progress bar appears on the bottom. But it never comes to an end. The app isn't deployed to the virtual device and then started.

[image: Screenshot]

**What's the cause? How can one fix the issue?**

I have tried it with two different projects and two different virtual devices. It seems to be the same everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Have Some Errors Your Project.
Check Logcat and Show Error Frist.

#Android_Emulator
#Android_Studio

Comment: "java.io.IOException: Failed to free 81163058 on storage device at /data ... " - I guess you are right.